# Can't connect to a SQL server remotely

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-connection, remote-access

I new to StackOverflow but maybe I may also ask a question. I also hope I can help others to find solutions regarding their issues.

So, here we go. I moved a database from an old SQL server to a new one. While trying to configure the application to use the new location of that database an error message shows up like this:

> Cannot connect to \MSSQLSERVER.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)
>
> The parameter is incorrect

So I started an analysis to solve this issue. And I checked those things:

- DNS resolution -> check
- ping to the new SQL Server -> check
- Firewall disabled -> check
- Remote connections on SQL Server enabled -> check

I was still receiving this error message. I configured the SSMS on the application server and ran that as a SQL server service user without any success.

- SQL Server browser is running
- TCP/IP is enabled using the default port 1433

I am not sure regarding the SQL server instance name. IMHO it is shown in the service name and the default instance name is MSSQLSERVER. The error message mentions that the connection string is not valid.

So, at this point I don't have any further ideas.

Greetings,
Chris

[EDIT] I don't use any specific connection string because I connect using SSMS.

[image]

[EDIT2]
I was able to connect locally using the hostname (not localhost).

All tests below do not use an instance name.

```
Test                          Result
-----------------------------------------------------
Locally, hostname, AD Auth    Success
Remote, hostname, AD Auth     The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context
Remote, FQDN, SQL Auth        Connection string is not valid
```

Comment: The error message states "Connection string is not valid" so add the connection string to your question (with obfuscated server name and credentials).

Comment: Can you connect to it using ODBC? Have you tried simply using the host name without the instance name? Knowing the host / instance name is critical to knowing the correct connection parameters so you really need to get to the bottom of that

Comment: If your service name is "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" then in all likelihood there is no instance name and you just need to connect to the server. For example this might be `myservername`, not  `myservername\MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: To save further confusion and incorrect assumptions, please post the connection string as requested

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Trying to connect via ODBC ends up in this error message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context.

Comment: That's a very different error. So first thing to do is get your connection string right, i.e. resolve the "Connection string is not valid" error. "Cannot generate SSPI context" has to do with windows authentication and is very different to "Connection string is not valid". Let solve one issue at a time. To proceed you really need to post your connection string

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Okay, one issue at a time. ;-) Can you provide any advice where i can find this connection string?

Comment: This is an example of a connection string: "Data Source=LT2000\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword" but since you are using SSMS, you aren't using that method. Can you just post the host name that you are using? YOu really need to confirm the correct host name for your SQL instance

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry, i can't do that due to regulations of the company to which the SQL server belongs to. But i'm pretty sure that i use the correct hostname. It's about the instance name where i am insecure. I'm going to post a screenshot.

Comment: You mention  in the answer below that you got it working. You also get an SSPI error as well as a different network error. You haven't worked out whether there is an instance name or not. This question is officially a hot mess... it get's this way sometimes...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This confirmation was mentioned not in this context. It was regarding to connect via RDP to the SQL Server remotely and I was able to use SSMS with that user as well. But these connecting were done locally on the SQL Server, not remotely. To conclude ... I am still in the starting position of that issue. Connecting remotely to the instance is not possible. Have take note the edit of my post, with the screenshot. Maybe this helps a little bit more?

Comment: So we have established that you can connect locally to it. Did you use localhost (or the mystery host name) or did you include an instance name? Can you add this information to the original question?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, if your service has `MSSQLSERVER` in it, then there is likely _no_ instance name, you just connect directly to the server name

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've added the information to original question. Trying to connect remotely without using an instance name ends up in an other error message. TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to <SERVERNAME>
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

Comment: Well that is the correct hostname since it works locally, and does not have a network error remotely. If you connect remotely with SQL authentication, it'll probably work. (I realise this is not the objective). Can you also try connecting with the full qualified name which is something like `hostname.thing.thing`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Connecting using the FQDN doensn't work as well and results into the  same error message regarding the unvalid connection string. But I have to disappoint you. Connecting remotely using the SQL authentication method result the unvalid connection string message as well. It's a crap.

Comment: Can you document all the things you have tried and all the error messages that you get in your question.

Comment: I have edited your question and added what I believe you've tried (after trawling through comments). There is something obvious here that is being lost in communication. I don't think I can assist any further.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for that work. :-) You're on point. Thanks for your assistance. I will investigate further on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Login Authentication Windows or SQL Server
Check your login Authentication whether its Windows or SQL Server.

Step 2: Use (.) (dot) instead of complete server name
If you are using local MS sql database then you can use (.) (dot) instead of complete server name.

Step 3: Enter Correct Host Name
Enter your correct host name: (hostname\SQLEXPRESS) my_hostname\SQLEXPRESS (in case of SQL Server Express) or (my_hostname\mssqlserver).

Step 4: Try localhost slash () then host name
You can also try localhost slash () then host name, here is sample as (localhost\SQLEXPRESS) or (localhost\mssqlserver).

Comment: *"Try localhost slash () then host name"* do you mean *Try `localhost` slash (`\\ `) and then the Instance name? The Host Name would be the name of the machine, which in this case would be localhost again, or the physical name. So you would end up with `localhost\localhost` or `localhost\MyPCName`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm quite sure using the correct hostname and authentication method. Step 2 doesn't fit for my case.

Comment: Sorry for mistake... It means localhost\SQLserver.

Comment: Check for the credentials. If you're quite sure about credentials then try using connection string just like this one: "Data Source=LT2000\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword"; Initial catalog is of course the name of your database. If that doesn't work, then use a data source wizard and enter your credentials, then test the connection and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :-) I this works correctly, i'm able to connect using the AD user.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? It’s not clear what you actually changed to get it working.